# Cosa significa "elargite" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *Non ora, non qui*, di Erri De Luca, ho letto:

> Restavo volentieri a guardare gli americani. Allora mi sembravano brutte le altre bambine, brutti anche i loro pianti. La bellezza, scoperta con emozione di estraneo, doveva per forza essere così: parlare un’altra lingua, 
>   appartenere a una ricchezza, essere infastidita perfino dall’ammirazione. Nessun bambino diventò amico di un americano. Alcuni, risentiti, erano ostili a quella gente venuta da lontano che abitava tra noi scansandoci. Io non potevo. Non mi offendeva il loro comportamento. Erano di un’altra terra dove le qualità che mi stupivano erano 
>   di sicuro **elargite** alla condizione di non farle toccare da nessuno straniero.

Ho cercato il verbo "elargire" in parecchi dizionari e ho visto che significa "donare generosamente". Non riesco a capire, però, quale sia il senso di "elargite" in questo passaggio. Qualcuno di voi me lo potrebbe spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nel passaggio da te citato ***[elargite](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/elargire/)*** significa, come giustamente hai scritto, donate, dispensate, distribuite con generosità.

Le qualità degli Americani, che tanto stupivano il narratore erano state distribuite, dispensate (o donate generosamente e in abbondanza) a condizione che esse fossero custodite gelosamente e in nessun modo condivise con gli stranieri.

Comment: Dov'è il comportamento offensivo? L'autore dice esplicitamente che _non_ era offeso dagli americani. Li vede solo come creature a sé, lontane, diverse.

Comment: Ok, elimino l'ultima parte...

Comment: Adesso mi sono accorta che quello che mi faceva non capire il senso della frase fosse la locuzione ["alla condizione"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/condizione) che segue questo "elargite": conoscevo l'espressione "a condizione", ma non sapevo che si potesse anche dire "alla condizione" e, per questa ragione, pensavo che "alla condizione di non farle toccare da nessuno straniero" dipendesse da "elargite".